# Automatically instantiate classes in Eclipse for autocomplete

Tags: java, eclipse, groovy

I'm working with Collibra java APIs in eclipse (which leverages the flowable workflow engine).
There are pre-instantiated classes in the engine, which eclipse (obviously) does not know about.

Is it possible to configure eclipse to automatically instantiate classes in order to provide autocomplete support?

i.e. to configure eclipse to perform the following code automatically?

```
import com.company.module.package.MyClass

MyClass myClass = new MyClass()
```

This way, the `myClass` variable would always be available for autocomplete without having to declare it every single time.

Edit: Even better, is there any way to configure eclipse to include variables loaded into the execution environment of flowable?
For example we would load one variable in one file, would the eclipse autocomplete be able to have access to that variable in another file?
In flowable, the syntax is:

```
execution.setVariable("myVariable", myVariable)
```

Comment: Are these groovy scripts?  Or do you want this support for Java sources as well?

Comment: Those are groovy scripts indeed. The library is java.

Comment: You can use BaseScript to simulate the variables that will be available in your runtime. Or you can use DSLD to provide inferencing hints that will support content assist as well.

Comment: Thank you so much! you put me onto the right path! In the end, I just have to type whichever variable I need, press ctrl+1 to bring the quick assist menu, define the declaring type as java.lang.Object and the Type to whatever class it should match, and voila! I will automatically create an entry into a xdsl file.
Do you want to make your comment into an answer so that I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [emilles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8395666/emilles) for putting me on the right track.
Here's the solution. This works when the Groovy developer tools plugin is installed.

1. open a new groovy script and type the name of the variable you want to add to content assist
2. press ctrl + 1 to bring the quick assist menu and press "Add inferencing suggestion"
3. Fill the information as described below
   [image: Groovy inferencing suggestion]

This will create an entry in a file located under your project root as .groovy/suggestions.xdsl

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
> <projectSuggestions>
>   <declaringtype type="groovy.lang.Script">
>     <property isActive="true" isStatic="false" name="execution" type="org.flowable.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntityImpl">
>         <doc/>
>     </property>
>   </declaringtype>
> </projectSuggestions>
> ```

From then on, the "execution" variable will be automatically recognized by eclipse as an instance of org.flowable.engine.impl.persistence.entity.ExecutionEntityImpl

[image: Inferencing suggestion example]